# Editing a UIViewController from another class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am trying to programmatically change the user interface of a `UIViewController` from another `NSObject` class. The problem is that I am unsure of how to access the `UIViewController`'s view from the `NSObject` class. So for example, in my `NSObject` class, I say something like:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

but I keep getting errors saying "Request for member "view" in something not a strut or union." Is there something I need to allow my `NSObject` class to see my `UIViewController`?

Comment: "self" always refers to the current object. In your case, saying "self.view" in some random object that doesn't have a property called "view" will cause this error. You could say viewController.view, if you had a viewController reference handy, which it sounds like is what you'll need.

Comment: How would I reference viewController?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you say "self" in a method, it refers to whatever object owns that method. So when you say `self.view`, you are really asking for the NSObject's view (which, needless to say, doesn't exist, unless you have specifically subclassed the NSObject to have a "view" property.

What you should do is give the NSObject class a property called `myController` or something in its interface declaration, or pass a `ViewController*` to any methods that need to access it.

For the property, you can say:

```
ViewController* myController;
```

in the NSObject sub-class interface declaration, or for the method way, add an argument to your NSObject sub-class' method:

```
- (void) someMethodThatTakesAViewController: (ViewController*) theViewController {
    //Do your stuff here
    theViewController.view = [[UIView alloc] init]; // Or whatever you want to do
}
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the header file for the object that is trying to change the view, add `@class <YOURVIEWCONTROLLER>;`, then in the `@interface` section, add `<YOURVIEWCONTROLLER> *viewController;` then outside `@interface` add `@property (nonatomic, retain) <YOURVIEWCONTROLLER> *viewController;`. Then in the main file add `@synthesize viewController;` and `#import "<YOURVIEWCONTROLLER.h"`. Then, to change the background colour, use `viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor <COLOUR>];`.

e.g:

Test.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Test2ViewController;

@interface Test : UIViewController {
    Test2ViewController *viewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Test2ViewController *viewController;
```

Test.m:

```
#import "Test.h"
#import "Test2ViewController.h"

@implementation Test

@synthesize viewController;

...

viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

...
```

Hope this helps

Edit: Make sure to call `[viewController release]` in your dealloc, otherwise you will have a leaky pipe ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can't access like this... you need to somehow pass UIViewController's view in your NSObject class...

Answer (score 0):

You can typecast your id to `UIViewcontroller`, like

```
[((UIViewController *)yourID).view addSubview:yourView.view];
```

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.